# How to stop Scrapy Selector wrap an xml with html?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I do this:

```
xmlstr="<root><first>info</first></root>"

res = Selector(text=xmlstr).xpath('.').getall()
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
['<html><body><root><first>info</first></root></body></html>']
```

How can I stop Selector wrapping the xml with html and body? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[scrapy.Selector](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#selector-objects) assumes html, but takes a `type` argument to change that.

> `type` defines the selector type, it can be `"html"`, `"xml"` or `None` (default).
>
> If `type` is `None`, the selector automatically chooses the best type based on `response` type (see below), or defaults to `"html"` in case it is used together with text.

So, to make an xml selector, simply use `Selector(text=xmlstr, type='xml')`